# How to save response body to variable and then execute it in jdbc request?

Tags: sql, jmeter, automated-tests

I have a query that returns me all routine names + EXEC in format `EXEC ROUTINE_NAME;`

And my task is to get all routine names in the first request and then execute all of them in the next JDBC request

I tried adding post processor that executes `vars.put("response", new String(data));` and then put `${response}` to my second JDBC request, but I always receive `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '$'.`

Comment: I managed to get it work by changing post processor code to ```response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
vars.put("exec_query", response);``` is there an any way to remove ```Output variables by position:``` from my response string, because this line won't allow me to execute my queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your `response` string to remove `Output variables by position:` by changing  your code as below

```
response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

String[] splitResponse = response.split("Output variables by position:");

vars.put("exec_query", splitResponse[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks you.  Your answer was helpful